# Why am I observing different behaviour of echo?

Tags: bash, quoting, echo

I observed the below behavior of echo

```
#!/bin/bash

x=" hello"

echo $x
echo "$x"
```

Now when I run the above code I get

```
ronnie@ronnie:~$ bash test.sh
hello
 hello
ronnie@ronnie:~$
```

So, can someone explain to me why `whitespace` in first case is not present in output and also points me to the documentation where this behavior is defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not the `echo` behavior. It is a bash behavior. When you use `echo $x` form the bash get the following command to process (treat `␣` as space):

```
echo␣␣hello
```

Then this command is tokenized and bash get two tokens: `echo` and `hello` thus the output is just `hello`

When you use the `echo "$x"` form then the bash has the following at the input of tokenizer:

```
echo␣"␣hello"
```

thus it has two tokens `echo` and `␣hello`, so the output is different.

Comment: I think you misinterpreted my question. what I am asking is why my leading white space is trimmed/lost in the first case.

Comment: nearly by the same reason. the command is tokenised and then each token is treated. if you like to include the space into the token you also has to escape it with backslash or enclose with quotes: `' whitespace'` or `\ whitespace`

Comment: I will rewrite the answer to reflect these changes

Comment: Thanks, that helped. Can you refer me some text where I can read more abt this `command tokenization`.

Comment: Well, `man bash`. It's a long reading, but if you want to study bash you have to read it.

Comment: @ronnie In the bash manual, read the section on [shell expansions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html#Shell-Expansions). The tokenization where whitespace becomes separators is [word splitting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html#Word-Splitting).

Comment: Just an editing hint. I find those underscores disorienting, maybe ␣ would look better: “(treat ␣ as spaces): `echo␣␣helo`”. [Wikipedia mentions it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_%28punctuation%29#Spaces_in_Unicode) as “Unicode also provides some visible characters to stand in for space when necessary – U+2423 | 9251 | Open box | Control Pictures | ␣”.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you see different output is because the `echo[1 space]Hello` line is syntactically equal 
to `echo[5 spaces]Hello`.  The whitespace is ignored, and the word 'Hello' is treated as the argument to `echo`.   The first line, in it's simplest form, is much the same as if you had said `echo "Hello"`.  In the second line, you have explicitly included a leading space as part of the argument to `echo`, with `echo " Hello"`.

In the first line, you are passing a 5 character string to `echo`, and in the second line you are passing a 6 character string to `echo`.

So, in fact, the behavior of `echo` is the same in both instances, it's just the string being passed to `echo` that changes.